# Notation for integration excluding endpoint

Tags: definite-integrals, notation

I was wondering if there is there a shorter way to write

$$\lim_{x\nearrow b}\int_a^x E$$

Can one use $\int_a^{b^-}$ to denote this?

Thanks

Comment: The integral is the same included the point $b$ or not. I dont think you need to symbolize it.

Comment: @Masacroso I think the only case in which one might want to distinguish the two cases is when the integrand function doesn't exist at a boundary point. But even in this case, the standard notation is accepted and taken to represent an improper integra.

Comment: Consider a random variable that is 1 with probability 1/2 and uniform on the interval $[0,1]$ with probability 1/2. Suppose that I am calculating the expected value of this random variable. It very much matters whether I include the point 1 in the integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent what you want in this way:

$$\int_{[a,b)}f(x)\mathrm d x$$

But many times you can write for many integrals

$$\int_{[a,b)}f(x)\mathrm d x=\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\mathrm d x$$

Comment: I wanted to say: We may be integrating with respect to a tempered distribution, for instance. (not Schwartz function).

Comment: It sound strange what you says but it is possible that is true for some kind of integral that I dont know. I dont know about Schwartz function. If you are sure that for your case this example doesnt apply then just write the integration over $[a,b)$.

Comment: It is true that the contribution at a point is zero if you take the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, but one can take any other measure, say one that gives measure 1/2 to point 1 and 1/2 to the interval $[0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks $\int_{[a,b)}$ looks very good.

Comment: @boinkboink Yes, I understand. If you use a counting measure for some points then it is the same that using a summation.